# How to mock the context in react fetching library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Hello everyone I have a problem with mocking the react fetching library function useQuery to pass the test of fetching data from api in container component. Right now I have an error that can't find the mocked tags in the dom. In console it still outputs, that only loader is visible.
I don't know how to wait till the loading indicator disappears.

I have following error:

```sh
Unable to find an element with the 
text: #1. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. 
In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
```

This is the container component test

```js
import React from 'react';
import { getByTestId } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ClientContextProvider } from 'react-fetching-library';

import { render, act } from 'tests';
import tags from 'api/mocks/tags-response.json';

import { TrendingTagsContainer } from './TrendingTagsContainer';

describe('TrendingTagsContainer component', () => {
  const client = {
    query: async () => ({
      error: false,
      status: 200,
      payload: tags,
    }),
    suspenseCache: false,
  };
  test('should render component with correct title and description', async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const { getByText, container } = render(
      <ClientContextProvider client={client}>
        <TrendingTagsContainer />
      </ClientContextProvider>,
    );
    expect(getByTestId(container, 'loader')).toBeInTheDocument();
    act(() => {
      jest.runAllTimers();
    });
    expect(getByText('#1')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```